# How to set open stock for Serial number Inventory Item first time for new NetSuite setup?

Tags: netsuite, erp, inventory-management

I am setting up New ERP setup with a serialized inventory in NetSuite. What is the best way to set open stock for serialized inventory?  All I can see the option is Inventory Adjustment Record. Is there any other better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An Inventory Adjustment or, Purchase Order and Item Receipt, or Work Order Completion / Assembly Build would all bring serialised inventory in to stock. Inventory Worksheets will not as per [SuiteAnswer 99378](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/99378). Inventory adjustments are relatively simple to import via CSV when working with serialised items. I found it works best if the item list, adjustment list, and serial number list (inventory detail), are all uploaded using the "Multiple files to upload" option. See [SuiteAnswer 51417](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/51417) for examples.

Comment: Thanks, Simon. "Multiple files to upload" is an interesting option. Will go through.